# Use only 1 AdView in Activity or multiple in fragments

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an app with 1 Activity and 4 fragments and want to show ads.

**Should I use only 1 AdView in Activity OR 4 AdView in every fragment? Which one is the best solution.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have designed your layout in a way that it will not cover the AdView from your activity like frame and adview in a linear layout with vertical orientation then you can use only one adview but if your fragment is overlapping over your activity(full screen) then you should use one adview for each fragment.

i think using one adview is a great idea, you can make your adview visible on ad loaded until you can show your fragment on whole screen.

Comment: adview is at bottom in activity and all fragments are not covering the adview, so according to you 1 adview in activity is a good approach